# Sentient computer fakes alien probe?

Tags: story-identification, sentience

I'm trying to find a novel that I read 10+ years ago (maybe), what I remember is:

- Computer becomes sentient, but hides it
- For some reason it interferes with some data (from a human probe? Or radio telescope?) to make it look like there is an alien probe out by Uranus / Saturn
- Someone finds evidence of the sentient computer in a memory dump from a telephone exchange
- The protagonist goes out to buy pizza, and then gets "buzzed in" by someone else, so the computer doesn't know he is in the building (as it controls the entry system?)

Cheers.

Comment: Very similar to Honey Moon in Hell, by Frederic brown (USSR and American computers fake space probe/encounter on the moon), but the other details don't match.

Comment: Similar to [Rogue Bolo](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?65004) by Keith Laumer